# Default Encryption - A Panacea or Placebo

Tags: encryption, cryptography, mobile

I wrote this on LinkedIn - [Discrete Discretion](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/discrete-discretion-ian-malloy)

My first question is:

Is it accurate to say that default encryption is a placebo?  Will default encryption only make end-users think they are secure instead of actually making them more secure?

Comment: Please stick to one question per question. Also, what do you mean by "default *decryption*"?

Comment: Default encryption will shift the attack points. We already see that in action.

Comment: apologies for the typo!  I have fixed it, thank you.

Comment: edited to one question, with the ancillary question left for clarification in case someone doesn't understand the use of 'placebo.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it accurate to say that default decryption is a placebo?

I assume you mean 'default *encryption*'. No, it is not a placebo. Of course it all depends on how it's *actually* implemented. I have read your post, and I'd like to point out that James Comey's example

> US-DoJ-FBI Director James Comey (pictured below) has been criticized
>   for his warnings of 'encryption by default' with Apple devices and
>   Google communications. He has used a hypothetical situation of a young
>   girl being kidnapped, and how encryption by default would disallow and
>   render impossible the ability to geo-locate the missing child if her
>   device is encrypted.

is seriously flawed. In his example **we do not care** whether the child's telephone is encrypted or not. What we want is a **control backdoor** into its GPS location service. This is completely orthogonal to the encryption thing:

- we can have a service that queries the GPS chip and sends the results to whoever sends a SMS containing the words "Squeamish Ossifrage", *whether the phone data are encrypted or not*.
- if we *don't* have a service allowing **remote access** to the phone, being able to read the data it contains, or that it stores in the cloud, is **completely worthless**. Unless mr. Comey is thinking that a phone might continuously store an encrypted GPS log on the cloud, which some services may well do *but is not required by his own use case*.

The power of locating/decrypting a phone can be easily escrowed to the child's parents, who can use it or empower the police if and when they see fit.

Can all encryption be cracked? It depends. Given omniscience and/or an infinite amount of time? *Probably*. In a finite amount of time and with negligible costs? **No way**.

> How difficult would it be for the FBI to crack Apple's encryption algorithms for iPhones?

I'm not familiar with that algorithm. But let's suppose Apple uses 256-bit AES, implements it properly and does not install any backdoors. A reasonable estimate of FBI difficulty in cracking a two-stage passphrase encryption (i.e. data is encrypted using a random key, itself encrypted in the device using the user's passphrase, *not* directly using the user's passphrase) is in the neighbourhood of "*pretty damn impossible*". The best prospect so far, Murphy-Robshaw linearization, knocks off about eighteen zeroes from the number of iterations required. About *sixty-seven* remain.

There are "[*suspicions*](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/09/06/us/nsa-foils-much-internet-encryption.html?pagewanted=all)" that some encryption algorithms are *flawed by design* to allow NSA (or whatever) to break the encryption. But that does not mean that every encryption can be cracked in practice - it just means that it can be comparatively cheaply *backdoored*.

Comment: the example you've quoted from my write up is based upon this talk he gave:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LRVGdmr000

Comment: BTW, it had no place in my answer, but I still found very interesting your view of the AoE and perception thereof. Pity I can't upvote on LinkedIn :-)

Comment: I don't think *just* encrypting the key with the user's passphrase would be enough -- even if it uses strong hashing that takes a full second per hash, it takes under a day to crack a 4-digit default passcode. The only way to secure with such a weak passcode is to have something like an HSM that will foil offline attacks. iPhones might have one, but just encrypting the key with another key derived from the passcode doesn't do it.

Comment: To that, iPhones allow 10 attempts before deleting all data.  Brute forcing isn't an option.

Comment: Yes, indeed. If such a weak password is used and the fact is known, so that only a limited keyspace needs to be bruteforced, security is of necessity nil. This gives back the user some choice: you *can* use a weak encryption *if you want*. The problem arises when a law *requires you to*.